# Replacing Colour Values with Related Column Values of a declared Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

_Hi, I have the following DAX measure and I would like to replace the XXXX section by the related colour of the "@Colour" column from the same _BarTable. I don't know how to do it ? Thanks for your help !
[Link to Pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv9ljw5vJ43gcapu8M?e=QboU2E)

```
VAR _BarTable=
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE('Crypto Data', 'Crypto Data'[timestamp]),
        "@Colour", IF(
                    [Current Price] = _YMaxValue, "Green",
                    IF( [Current Price] = _YMinValue, "Red",
                    _LineColor)
                   ),
        "@Bars",    "<rect x='" & INT(150 * DIVIDE('Crypto Data'[timestamp] - _XMinDate, _XMaxDate - _XMinDate)) &
                    "' width='1' stroke='" & XXXX & "' stroke-width='1' y='" &
                    50 -  INT(50 * DIVIDE([Current Price] - _YMinValue, _YMaxValue - _YMinValue)) & "' height='" &
                    INT(50 * DIVIDE([Current Price] - _YMinValue, _YMaxValue - _YMinValue)) &
                    "'  style='fill:" & XXXX & "'/>"
    )
```

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
VAR _BarTable=
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE('Crypto Data', 'Crypto Data'[timestamp]),

        "@Colour", IF(
                    [Current Price] = _YMaxValue, "Green",
                    IF( [Current Price] = _YMinValue, "Red",
                    _LineColor)
                   ),
    
        "@Bars",   
         
         VAR x = IF(
                    [Current Price] = _YMaxValue, "Green",
                    IF( [Current Price] = _YMinValue, "Red",
                    _LineColor)
                   )
         RETURN
         "<rect x='" & INT(150 * DIVIDE('Crypto Data'[timestamp] - _XMinDate, _XMaxDate - _XMinDate)) &
                    "' width='1' stroke='" & x & "' stroke-width='1' y='" &
                    50 -  INT(50 * DIVIDE([Current Price] - _YMinValue, _YMaxValue - _YMinValue)) & "' height='" &
                    INT(50 * DIVIDE([Current Price] - _YMinValue, _YMaxValue - _YMinValue)) &
                    "'  style='fill:" & x & "'/>"
    )
```